# background video css (not fullscreen)

Tags: css, html, html5-video

Good day to everyone!
I have a question about background-video,I have it attached to the whole page,but need it just to be embedded at the top. Can anyone tell me what's the problem?
Huge thanks!
HTML:

```
<video autoplay loop poster="video-bg.jpg" id="bgvid">
    <source src="video-bg.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="video-bg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

CSS:

```
video#bgvid { 
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background: url(video-bg.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; 
}
@media screen and (max-device-width: 800px) {
    html {
         background: url(video-bg.jpg) #000 no-repeat center center fixed;
    }
    #bgvid {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Need to embed at top means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove `min-width/height: 100%;`
Than replace `transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);` with `transform: translateX(-50%);` to move element only horizontally
Finally change `top: 50%;` to `top: 0;`

If you wish to scroll also video when scrolling page replace `position: fixed` with `position: absolute;`

```css
#bgvid {
  background: none #aaa !important;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}
#bgvid {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    /*min-width: 100%;*/
    /*min-height: 100%;*/
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    z-index: -100;
    background: url(video-bg.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; 
}
@media screen and (max-device-width: 800px) {
    html {
         background: url(video-bg.jpg) #000 no-repeat center center fixed;
    }
    #bgvid {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="bgvid">VIDEO HERE</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

position is fixed so it will be fixed to the whole page. Use `position: absolute;`  also change the height & width.